# How to get rid of "missing files" message in XCode4?

Tags: xcode4

I have this iPad app using Storyboard.  There are some file that are marked as missing which used to be in the app.  The message is really annoying me...

[image]

I did a clean, re-build, but they are still there.  How do I get rid of the messages?

Comment: Are you using version control?

Comment: Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.  It is the solution to remove them from SVN via Terminal.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like they're still held under version control. The solution for me has been to force remove them via Terminal.

Comment: Yep, that's what I finally did, only deleted and re-checked out... thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete them from the filesystem directly (e.g using Finder or the terminal) instead of through Xcode?  Your project doesn't mirror the filesystem, so when you delete files externally, Xcode still expects them to be there.  Find the references in the project navigator in the left-hand panel and remove them.  In future, remove the files through Xcode and it will ask you if the files need to be deleted from the filesystem or not.

If you've already done this and you are still seeing the problem, it's probably an Xcode bug.  Quit and reopen Xcode.

Comment: quit and re-start XCode didn't help... and the files are NOT in the File Navigator... everything appears ok, but I don't like to see the messages, for who knows what will happen down the line... :D